# How to separate string specific word in swift

Tags: swift, string

For example)

```
var str = "ABCDEF"
let result = str.someMethod("B")

result[0] // "A"
result[1] // "B"
result[2] // "CDEF"

let result2 = str.someMethod("A")
result2[0] // "A"
result2[1] // "BCDEF"

var str2 = "BBBAAA"
let result3 = str2.someMethod("B")
result3[0] // "B"
result3[1] // "B"
result3[2] // "B"
result3[3] // "AAA"

var str3 = "BABBCDEDBB"
let result4 = str3.someMethod("B")
result4[0] // "B"
result4[1] // "A"
result4[2] // "B"
result4[3] // "B"
result4[4] // "CDED"
result4[5] // "B"
result4[6] // "B"
```

How can I that???

This method is a little different component(separatedBy: )

Maybe it should work this way

Comment: @Cristik I tried only component(separatedBy: ). I don't know how to access that.

Comment: So what should be the expected behaviour of `someMethod`? Individual elements until the match, and the rest of the elements after? How about the case where `B` is present multiple times in the string?

Comment: @Cristik I add another case.

Comment: But what if `B` is also at the end of the string? What should the method do then?

Comment: @Cristik Add another case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it will work for string and char

```
func getResult(input:String, separator:String)->[String]{
    var arr = input.components(separatedBy: separator)
    var newArray = [String]()
    var count = 0
    while count < arr.count {
        if let lastObj = newArray.last{
            if lastObj == separator{
                newArray.append(arr[count] == "" ? separator : arr[count])
            }else{
                if arr[count] == ""{
                    newArray.append(separator)
                }else{
                    newArray.append(separator)
                    newArray.append(arr[count] == "" ? separator : arr[count])
                }
            }
        }else{
            newArray.append(arr[count] == "" ? separator : arr[count])
        }
        count += 1
    }
    return newArray
}

print(getResult(input: "ABCABDEA", separator: "AB"))
print(getResult(input: "ABCABDEA", separator: "A"))
```

> ["AB", "C", "AB", "DEA"]
>
> ["A", "BC", "A", "BDE", "A"]

Comment: @allanWay happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

try with below method,

```
func someMethod(input: String, fullString: String) -> [String] {
    var array: [String] = []
    var string:String = ""

    for (index, char) in fullString.enumerated() {
        if String(char) == input {
            if string != "" {
                array.append(string)
                string = ""
            }
            array.append(input)
        } else {
            string.append(char)
            if index == fullString.count-1 {
                array.append(string)
            }
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

and call it like this way,

```
    let str = "BABBCDEDBB"
    let result = someMethod(input: "B", fullString: str)
    print(result)
```

You will get following output,

```
["B", "A", "B", "B", "CDED", "B", "B"]
```

Comment: So nice. But there is a problem. It does not work on words such as two-digit, three-digit, and so on. for example) "BB" or "ABC"...

Comment: @allanWay what is the desired output for two digit and three digit? please update your question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete answer written as a `String` extension. This solution fits all of your listed needs plus it also handles cases where you pass in multi-characters searches.

```
extension String {
    func someMethod(_ input: String) -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()
        var str = self
        repeat {
            if str.hasPrefix(input) {
                result.append(input)
                str.removeFirst(input.count)
            } else if let range = str.range(of: input) {
                result.append(String(str[..<range.lowerBound]))
                str.removeSubrange(..<range.lowerBound)
            } else {
                if !str.isEmpty {
                    result.append(str)
                }
                break
            }
        } while (true)
        return result
    }
}

let strs = ["ABCDEF", "BBBAAA", "BABBCDEDBB"]
for str in strs {
    let result = str.someMethod("B")
    print("B in \(str) -> \(result)")
}

print("A in \(strs[0]) -> \(strs[0].someMethod("A"))")
print("BB in \(strs[2]) -> \(strs[2].someMethod("BB"))")
```

Output:

> B in ABCDEF -> ["A", "B", "CDEF"]
>   B in BBBAAA -> ["B", "B", "B", "AAA"]
>   B in BABBCDEDBB -> ["B", "A", "B", "B", "CDED", "B", "B"]
>   A in ABCDEF -> ["A", "BCDEF"]
>   BB in BABBCDEDBB -> ["BA", "BB", "CDED", "BB"]

Comment: Perfect and nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got what you need from the question: to split a string and keep the delimiters. You can achieve this via a nice `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func splitAndKeep(separator: Character) -> [String] {
        let separatorIndexes = enumerated().flatMap { $0.1 == separator ? index(startIndex, offsetBy: $0.0) : nil }
        let separatorRangeIndexes = separatorIndexes.flatMap { [$0, index(after: $0)] }
        let splitIndexes = [startIndex] + separatorRangeIndexes + [endIndex]
        let splitRangesEnds = zip(splitIndexes, splitIndexes.dropFirst()).filter { $0.0 < $0.1 }
        return splitRangesEnds.map { String(self[$0.0..<$0.1]) }
    }
}
```

`splitAndKeep` gradually computes the information needed to build the array of components to use.

Usage:

```
print("ABCDEF".splitAndKeep(separator: "B"))
// ["A", "B", "CDEF"]

print("ABCDEF".splitAndKeep(separator: "A"))
// ["A", "BCDEF"]

print("BBBAAA".splitAndKeep(separator: "B"))
// ["B", "B", "B", "AAA"]


print("BABBCDEDBB".splitAndKeep(separator: "B"))
// ["B", "A", "B", "B", "CDED", "B", "B"]
```